# I need to link two tables so that when I filter on one, the other is filtered as well

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Microsft 2016 and I have two tables on two sheets. They share a common column. I want to be able to somehow link them so that when I filter on one table in the common column, the other table automatically filters in that common column. The common column does not have unique values- some of them are repeated and some might be missing from one table to the other, but they are the same for the most part. I just want to do this so it is quicker to filter and I don't have to type in the same filter in both tables.

Comment: Hi @Steve ,, check my post I've solved the issue,, read instructions carefully before proceed ,,, I've suggested VBA macro because it's the only way to fix the issue,, please [edit] your post & add few line that VBA method is also required,,, also add new TAG `vba` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*What you are trying is only possible by using VBA macro, and you need to follow below shown steps:*

[image]

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Create two TABLEs either in one sheet or in two different Sheets.
- Enter Criteria (the data/value are common in both Tables), in cells T43 & T44.
- Hit DEVELOPER Tab then select DESIGN mode, find INSERT left to it.
- Form INSERT, ACTIVE X Controls, select Command button and draw on Sheet.

[image]

- Select the Command button and RIGHT Click & hit PROPERTIES.
- Now From the list find CAPTION and Change it as I did, or you may put name of your choice also.
- Double Click the Command button, Excel will open VB editor.
- COPY & PASTE VBA code between,

  ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Copy below show code here,,,

   End Sub
  ```

---

**Code to Copy & Paste:**

```
lookupdata1 = Range("T43").Value
lookupdata2 = Range("T44").Value

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
 Criteria1:=Array("=" & Range("T43").Value, "=" & Range("T44").Value)


ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
  Criteria1:=Array("=" & Range("T43").Value, "=" & Range("T44").Value)
```

---

- Press ALT+Q to return to the Sheet.
- Turn Off the DESIGN mode from DEVELOPER Tab.
- SAVE the Workbook as Macro Enabled.
- Now hit the Command Button.

*You find that Excel has filtered both TABLEs at once on common Data*

**N.B.** *You can add more Criteria, in that case you need to edit this line*

```
 Criteria1:=Array("=" & Range("T43").Value, "=" & Range("T44").Value)
```

- For example:

  ```
  Criteria1:=Array("=" & Range("T43").Value, "=" & Range("T44").Value, "=" & Range("T45").Value)
  ```
- You may adjust Cell reference and the Criteria alos as needed.